# Why are Lat/Lon Coordinates often displayed as Lon/Lat in data sets?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

Why are Lat/Lon Coordinates often displayed as Lon/Lat in data sets?

Comment: this is a common problem, here are some previous discussions -
http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/latlon-or-lonlat-whats-the-right-way-to-display-coordinates-and-inputs

http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99769/why-some-coordinate-systems-define-x-axis-as-northings-and-some-as-easting/99781#99781

Very exhaustive discussion at http://wiki.osgeo.org/wiki/Axis_Order_Confusion