# What is a term to describe a latitude OR longitude value but not both together?

Tags: design, documentation

I have a location of north 45 degrees, west 90 degrees. This is the coordinate of the point. What is each component of this coordinate called? I'm looking for a generic term to describe either component but not both together (that's the coordinate).

Comment: I'm not sure whether I have misunderstood the question. What is wrong with "latitude" and "longitude"?

Comment: Related: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/99769/

Comment: You might get good answers but from a bit different point of view also from http://english.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 4):

I found this [definition for Cartesian Coordinates at Dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Cartesian%20coordinates):

> **Cartesian coordinates in Technology**
>
> mathematics, graphics  (After Renee Descartes, French philosopher and
>   mathematician) 
>   A **pair of numbers**, (x, y), defining the position of a
>   point in a two-dimensional space by its perpendicular projection onto
>   two axes which are at right angles to each other. x and y are also
>   known as the abscissa and ordinate.  The idea can be generalised to
>   any number of independent axes.

I think you would call either the latitude part or the longitude part **a coordinate**.  Both the latitude and longitude parts together are **the coordinates**.

In other words, where you say:

> This is the coordinate of the point.

I would say:

> These are the coordinates of the point.

It seems to be used by GPS/GIS in a similar manner.  For example, I saw this at http://www.gps-coordinates.net/:

> **Latitude, longitude and address of any point on Google Maps**
>
> Click directly on the map to get an address and its GPS coordinates.
>   The latitude coordinate and the longitude coordinate are displayed on
>   the left column and on the map.

Comment: I don't think that's correct. A Cartesian coordinate (singular) is composed of the abscissa (x) and ordinate (y).

Comment: I think it would be possible to use "coordinates" for a single point (e.g. "take the coordinates for the building from the map"). So it could be ambiguous about what is meant.

Comment: @DenaliHardtail Don't know I agree with that. A coordinate (singular) is actually short for coordinate pair - hence an x coordinate and a y coordinate. It's even in the word (co). I wonder how a linguistics expert would determine 'proper' use of coordinate vs coordinates. Maybe the latter only applies to the components of a point and not multiple points? Maybe both? Moose is both singular and plural... But along your lines of thinking (with abscissa and ordinate), I would say that latitude and longitude *are* the words you want - see comments on my answer and BradHards answer.

Comment: I agree with @DenaliHardtail. It says it directly in the answer - each component is either abscissa or ordinate. Together they form a COordinate (or COordinates).

Answer (score 1):

A **coordinate** is *a number in an ordered pair* that names the location of a point on the coordinate plane. The first number in the ordered pair is called the abscissa and the second number is the ordinate. (Math Goodies Glossary)

**coordinate**: *Each of a group of numbers* used to indicate the position of a point, line, or plane. (Oxford Living Dictionary)

A coordinate is ***one*** of the numbers in an ordered pair (or group), *not the pair itself*. Since your pair indicates a position on the earth's surface (45N, 90W), each component would be a **geographic coordinate**. The first (geo) coordinate indicates latitude, and the second coordinate is the longitude.

Answer (score 0):

I think it depends on your target audience, but ideally you'd refer to them as the latitude or longitude as appropriate (i.e. say what you mean).

If you really need a generic term (e.g. you can't fix the user interface), then perhaps you could use one of:

- "number of degrees"
- "coordinate part"
- "coordinate element", or
- "coordinate angle".

Answer (score 0):

[Easting and Northing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Easting_and_northing) are the terms I typically hear when not specifically saying lat/lon(g). While the words imply a direction, west 90 degrees would simply be an Easting of -90.

Note it is understood with lat/lon you're starting from the Prime Meridian and equator. An Easting/Northing can start from *any* baseline, so if that's not specified you don't really know exactly where you're talking about. Easting and Northing are generic terms, not specific to a single coordinate system.

The UTM zones, for example, all have a False Easting value. This shifts the Y axis to the west so that all coordinates within the zone have positive values instead of possibly having negative values. You *can* have a coordinate with a negative value, but that just means it falls outside the area the zone was intended for.

You might also say meridian (longitude) and parallel (latitude).

Comment: Certainly valid for some audiences, but it has a more technical meaning (e.g. my Mum and Dad probably wouldn't understand those terms in the same way I would). If I heard it, I'd be expecting UTM / MGRS or something similar, rather than some degrees.

Comment: @BradHards I don't know about "more technical" but I agree they're not perfect. As asker points out in comment, in Cartesian coordinate *mathematics* (and only 2D? I don't see or know of another name for z when you hit 3D, or if these still apply) the x and y are known as abscissa and ordinate. However in a geographic CRS they're simply known as *the* longitude and *the* latitude (which perhaps negates OP's question altogether). Easting and northing might be more suited to only projected CRS. Maybe this requires a geodesy expert to answer at a technical level?