# Trying to add lat long points to a map, not getting an ok button

Tags: qgis, csv

I add "Data Source Manager" then "Delimited Text" and i select the x y and coordinate system but there is no OK button?

just add and close add just restarts the process. how do i get the ok button?

[image]

Comment: Your lat and long information are incorrect. There are also text inside the two columns. Uncheck `Discard empty fields`

Comment: Apart from the crud in the table which you will need to filter out in Excel or similar you have X and Y the wrong way around X=lon and Y=lat https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/does-y-mean-latitude-and-x-mean-longitude-in-every-gis-software though that won't stop you from hitting the OK button, it will just give you data that is *nowhere near where you expect it to be*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question there is no OK button, you just have to click the Add button to add your layer, but as you may wish to add other layer the data source manager stay open and is reset to initial state. (after clicking 'add' the layer should appear in the layer panel, if that's not happening it's probably because your setting and/or file have problem, see the comment to fix it and always check in the sample data window that everything look good before clicking the add button)

When you're finish with the data source manager you just close it with the close button.