# Correctly mapping CSV with x y coordinates when converting to correct CRS doesn't work

Tags: arcgis-desktop, coordinate-system, arcmap, xy

I have a CSV file that I'd like to map using lat long coordinates. The file has a field containing four coordinate points (see image below), but the first two and second two are nearly identical, so I just take the first two and separate into different columns. Then I import into ArcMap and am able to map. The points don't display properly on the map even after I convert to the CRS they were originally in.

What else can I try here?

[image]

Comment: Please [Edit] the question to describe *exactly* how you went about converting the CRS.

Comment: Which CRS are your original (linestring) coordinates in?

Comment: WGS84. I have tried both specifying this system when displaying XY data and converting to it using the project tool after plotting the data and neither work.

Comment: To confirm, these are all close to the equator (Ghana?) Are you using the latitude for Y value?  What's wrong with the display XY data?

Comment: The coordinates are not looking right.  Where are these features?

Comment: Indeed, these are supposed to be located in Ghana, but when I display they are showing up south of where they should be.

Comment: These are points. The table is actually an exported attribute table. For reasons beyond my control, it's not possible to export the shapefile, so basically I need to recreate it.

Comment: Make sure you are not switching Lat and Long when you import. ESRI displays them as Long (x) & Lat (y). Mixing them up could cause placement errors.  Another post about what I mean: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11626/does-y-mean-latitude-and-x-mean-longitude-in-every-gis-software/11628

Also make sure the CRS of your Data Frame is defined to the same coordinate system before you import so it will line up with your basemap instead of Projection on the Fly.

Comment: Got it. I was able to sort it out. Thank you all for your comments.