# Leaflet geojson coordinate problem

Tags: geojson, leaflet

I just started to play with leaflet/geojson a little. But my coordinates are not rendered properly and I have no clue what is going on.

My coordinates are: `52.23943, 4.97599`. They work correct with the `setView` function.

```
var map = L.map('leaflet_map').setView([52.23943, 4.97599], 15);
```

But using a geojasonFeature they are, hmmm, 'projected', somewhere east of Somalia.

```
var geojsonFeature = {
            "type": "Feature",
            "properties": {
            "name": "Coors Field",
            "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
            "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "type": "Point",
                "coordinates": [52.23943, 4.97599]
            }
        };
        var myLayer = L.geoJson().addTo(map);
        myLayer.addData(geojsonFeature).bindPopup("I am a gjson point.");
```

Anyone who knows what is happening here?

**EDIT**

Out of pure curiosity, I changed the coordinates around `[4.976143930893815,52.23925499011473]` and the point appears at its correct location. A known bug!?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I wouldn't call it a bug, just a matter of confusing and contradictory standards.

When talking about geographic locations, we usually use Lat-long. This has been codified in the [ISO 6709 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709).

When dealing with Cartesian coordinate geometry, we generally use X-Y. Many GIS systems, work with a Geographic Location as a special case of a 2 D coordinate point, where the X represents the longitude and Y represents the Latitude. This order of coordinates, is exactly opposite that of the regular Lat-long notion.

Coming to your problem:

The map.setView takes a [l.LatLong](http://leafletjs.com/reference.html#latlng) as an input, where the first cordinate is a Latitude, and the second is Longitude.

Hence when you want `52.23N, 4.97E`, you pass in `[52.23943, 4.97599]`

The [GeoJSON standard](http://geojson.org/geojson-spec.html#positions) says that for any point, the first parameter is the X Coordinate (i.e. Longitude) and second parameter is the Y coordinate (i.e. Latitude);

Hence when you want `52.23N, 4.97E` in GeoJSON, you need to pass  `[4.97599, 52.23943]`

For further reading, go through this [Q&A](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/latlon-or-lonlat-whats-the-right-way-to-display-coordinates-and-inputs)

Comment: Indeed a matter of confusion. I just read the geojson spec and indeed you are absolutely right. Here is the quote _The order of elements must follow x, y, z order (easting, northing, altitude for coordinates in a projected coordinate reference system, or longitude, latitude, altitude for coordinates in a geographic coordinate reference system)_

Comment: @LarsVegas The origin of this issue is the English Language. We usually say Lat-long when we are talking about the geographic location and use X-Y when are talking about coordinate geometry.

Comment: A summary of which programs and libraries use X,Y and which Y,X pair ordering: https://macwright.org/lonlat/, courtesy Tom MacWrite

Comment: thanks for this helpful answer... but WHY did geojson choose to do this??

Answer (score 1):

I ve just bumped upon this issue. To anyone experiencing this problem and has a considerable number of lat,long data pairs, you can use the following js:

```
var a = "[LatLng(37.43943, 25.30563)],[LatLng(37.4367, 25.30495)],[LatLng(37.43071, 25.29945)],[LatLng(37.42362, 25.30426)],[LatLng(37.42089, 25.31113)],[LatLng(37.41489, 25.31113)],[LatLng(37.41053, 25.30769)],[LatLng(37.40235, 25.30563)],[LatLng(37.40562, 25.31525)],[LatLng(37.41816, 25.31937)],[LatLng(37.42307, 25.3228)],[LatLng(37.40889, 25.33104)],[LatLng(37.4078, 25.33722)],[LatLng(37.41598, 25.33791)],[LatLng(37.40344, 25.35027)],[LatLng(37.40726, 25.3688)],[LatLng(37.42253, 25.39009)],[LatLng(37.4138, 25.39902)],[LatLng(37.42907, 25.4052)],[LatLng(37.42961, 25.41962)],[LatLng(37.44215, 25.42442)],[LatLng(37.44543, 25.45807)],[LatLng(37.46287, 25.4615)],[LatLng(37.47595, 25.46013)],[LatLng(37.47104, 25.42786)],[LatLng(37.48249, 25.42923)],[LatLng(37.48358, 25.41)],[LatLng(37.49502, 25.40588)],[LatLng(37.49447, 25.38597)],[LatLng(37.49066, 25.3791)],[LatLng(37.46941, 25.38254)],[LatLng(37.46178, 25.37773)],[LatLng(37.4754, 25.35988)],[LatLng(37.4972, 25.35782)],[LatLng(37.50047, 25.34203)],[LatLng(37.49774, 25.32761)],[LatLng(37.49229, 25.3228)],[LatLng(37.4912, 25.3125)],[LatLng(37.4814, 25.30907)],[LatLng(37.47268, 25.31113)],[LatLng(37.46341, 25.32692)],[LatLng(37.44597, 25.32692)],[LatLng(37.42798, 25.3228)],[LatLng(37.43943, 25.30563)]".split("],[");
var b = a.map(function(x) { 
    var couple= (/\d+.\d+, \d+.\d+/g).exec(x).toString();
    var splitted = couple.split(", ");
    return "["+splitted[1]+","+splitted[0]+"]";
                            } );
b.join();
```

**Edit:** according to this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983078/leaflet-swap-the-coordinates-when-use-geojson), apparently there is also this method:

`L.GeoJSON.coordsToLatLng()`.

I havent use it but it seems promising.

Comment: A useful function. Most inputs would probably be bare coordinate pair lists though - `[[60.672744462452,-135.02487602415],[60.673011537554,-135.02487602415]]`. I've also seen but not used the [geojson-flip](https://www.npmjs.com/package/geojson-flip) nodejs module.

Comment: Ty for your kind words. It was mostly a solution of the last moment as I was working on a tight schedule. There is actually a method provided by the leaflet library to do exactly that as I ve learned later (cant remember now which but I can check if you want).

Comment: The name of the Leaflet method would be helpful! I haven't been able to find it, and the geojson-flip module I mentioned above doesn't work with my data.

Comment: Found something in [tag:turf], which is a big well supported module: http://turfjs.org/docs/#flip

Comment: Sorry I ve been swamped on my own headaches.. I am pretty sure it was a leaflet method. I ll try to have a thorough look later on.

Comment: hey, sorry for the long delay, but here is what I was talking about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35983078/leaflet-swap-the-coordinates-when-use-geojson