# Problem while Reprojecting

Tags: spatialite, coordinate-system, srid

When I try to transform geometries from SRID 2321 to 4326, the transformed coordinates are swapping. Why is this happening?

Below are the details

**Source**

SRID - EPSG:2321

Source Data Projection Definition:

- WGS84 Bounds: 31.5000, 35.9000, 34.5000, 42.1000
- Projected Bounds:364573.0642, 3975550.1410, 635426.9358, 4663916.1654
- Area: Turkey - 31.5°E to 34.5°E

below are the sample points :

- 470343.6,4402310.3
- 470105.0,4402410.8
- 470236.5,4402700.1

**Destination**

SRID - EPSG:4326

Below are the sample points after conversion:

- 32.6539666652,39.753664831
- 32.6511781435,39.7545616174
- 32.6526994043,39.7571716999

When I try to project these point on a Google map they are referencing to Iraq when they should refer to Turkey.

But when I tried with reversing the coordinates of the above points then they are referencing to correct locations on Google maps

Why is this happening? Do I miss anything?

**EDIT:**

Software used for conversion : Spatialite v 4.1.1 and this conversion is
confirmed using this [link](http://cs2cs.mygeodata.eu).

Actually my source data is from ESRI personal geodatabase .mdb file. I used QGIS to import them into Spatialite and when I try to project them on google/Apple maps all data is referencing to a different location.

Comment: What do you mean the coordinates are swapping? 32.6539666652,39.753664831 is actually 32.6539666652E,39.753664831N, which does fall in Turkey. I think you might be running into a confusion similar to this: http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/54066/442

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When talking about geographic locations, we usually say and use Lat-long. This has been codified in the [ISO 6709 standard](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709).

When dealing with Cartesian coordinate geometry, we generally use X-Y. Many GIS systems, work with a Geographic Location as a special case of a 2 D coordinate point, where the X represents the longitude and Y represents the Latitude. This order of coordinates, is *exactly opposite* that of the regular Lat-long notion.

SO when Spatialite gives `32.6539666652,39.753664831`, it is actually  `32.6539666652E,39.753664831N` since the first coordinate is X (i.e longitude) & second one is Y (i.e. Latitude).

If you put just `32.6539666652,39.753664831` in Google Maps, it assumes that you are giving coordinates in ***Lat-Long***, and not in ***XY***. It parses the coordinates as: `32.6539666652N ,39.753664831E`. That's why it shows you the point in Iraq

So I'll say that this isn't a bug, just a matter of confusing and contradictory standards.

For similar Issues, go through these two Q&A:

- [leaflet geojson coordinate problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/54065/)
- [LatLon or LonLat, what's the "right" way to display coordinates and inputs?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/)