# Are [-90,-180] and [90,180] theoretically the same point?

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates

I'm not an expert in GIS.  To my understanding `-180° longitude` and `+180° longitude` are the same, meaning that if I draw two vertical lines on the map along this longitude, they will overlap.

But does this work for latitudes, too? Is `-90° latitude` equivalent to `+90° latitude`? If that is the case, as the title says this would mean that `-90, -180` and `90, 180` are equivalent, is that correct?

Comment: Well, they may be, in whatever universe has 180 degrees north and south. But even if we reverse standard {X,Y} coordinate order, the North Pole and South Pole are not considered to be the same location.

Comment: so for longitudes you have [-180,180) and for latitudes [-90,90] ?

Comment: i know it's a silly question, but couldn't find the answer with google :(

Comment: You don't really need Google for this. It's pretty basic geometry.

Comment: @Vince Lat/Long rather than X/Y I think is probably the reason for the coordinate order.  See [LatLon or LonLat, what's the “right” way to display coordinates and inputs?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/6037/latlon-or-lonlat-whats-the-right-way-to-display-coordinates-and-inputs) and [ISO 6709 - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_6709)

Comment: If you google it, the answer will came (for sure).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, they are not the same place. `+90` would be the North pole, and `-90` would be the South pole. For them to be the same place it would need to be on the equator, so `0, 180` = `0, -180`

This image might help make it clear

[image]

From [Geographic Coordinate System - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_system)